# WCF Data Service - Service Operation throws a Bad Request Exception!

Tags: linq-to-entities, odata, wcf-data-services

I'm currently working on a service-oriented application that uses WCF Data Service to communicate with Data Provider Layer which is LINQ to Entity.

I also created a stored procedure in my SQL Database that returns a complex type.

Because WCF Data Service, doesn't support Imported functions such as Stored procedures, I had to create a ServiceOperation that calls my my stored procedure like the following:

```
[WebGet()]
    public IEnumerable<AlphaKaran.DataProvider.CalculateTaskInfoDetails_Result> 
        CalculateTaskInfoDetails(int statementListId, int postId)
    {
        var c = new AlphaKaran.DataProvider.AlphaKaranEntities();

        return c.CalculateTaskInfoDetails(statementListId, postId);
    }
```

When I call this method from the browser, I throws an Exception:
**Bad Request - Error in Query Syntax**
The Url of my method is this:

```
http://localhost/DataService/Alphakaran.svc/CalculateTaskInfoDetails()?statementListId=10&postId=4
```

What's wrong with this? Please help me if you know any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax instead:

```
http://localhost/DataService/Alphakaran.svc/CalculateTaskInfoDetails?statementListId=10&postId=4
```

Make sure you are returning an Entity as well (i.e. is `CalculateTaskInfoDetails_Result` a valid entity)?